# ASP.net PageAsyncTaks - how to pass parameter to the task?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I'm looking to make a series of web service calls (all to the same service, different paramters passed each time).

I've been doing a bit of reading about PageAsyncTasks, and they look right, but not sure how to pass a parameter down to each call to the service.  Much simplified example below - real world will be looping around and changing the parameter before registering each task to be performed:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{    
    base.OnInit(e);     
    int myParameter = 1;

    var task = new PageAsyncTask(BeginRequest, EndRequest, null, null, true);
    RegisterAsyncTask(task);    
} 

IAsyncResult BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
{    
    var service = new ServiceClient();    

    return service.BeginServiceCall(<How to get the parameter to the async call?>, 
                cb, service);
} 

... End request etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th argument ("state" in our example) can be used to pass in an object as a parameter to your task.  If you have more than one parameter that needs to be passed in, you'll want to create a seperate class (a DataTransferObject for example) that hold all of these parameters that would be used by your task.

Comment: I was just coming to that conclusion from some other reading.  Thanks for the answer.