# How to use HttpClient async methods with WebForm's RegisterAsyncTask in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using HttpClient in ASP.NET framework 4.0. All example are I have seen using OnBeginXX/OnEndXXX or async/await(4.5) with RegisterAsyncTask. I need to ask how to make RegisterAsyncTask work with HtpClient's GetByteArrayAsync(or similar). Note this is ASP.NET 4.0?

**Update:** Just found that in [4.5 you have more overloads than 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx),

```
Public method   PageAsyncTask(Func<Task>)   Initializes a new instance of the PageAsyncTask class using an event handler that enables the task to be handled.
Public method   PageAsyncTask(Func<CancellationToken, Task>)    Initializes a new instance of the PageAsyncTask class using an event handler that enables the task to be canceled.
Public method   PageAsyncTask(BeginEventHandler, EndEventHandler, EndEventHandler, Object)  Initializes a new instance of the PageAsyncTask class using the default value for executing in parallel.
Public method   PageAsyncTask(BeginEventHandler, EndEventHandler, EndEventHandler, Object, Boolean) Initializes a new instance of the PageAsyncTask class using the specified value for executing in parallel.
```

Any other solution?

**Update 2:** I think TPL is not supported in 4.0 with recommended RegisterAsyncTask. Need to use [HttpWebRequest with RegisterAssyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214418/how-to-use-pageasynctask-with-webrequest-for-multiple-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `async`/`await` on ASP.NET 4.0. This probably means you cannot use `HttpClient` either.

So, I recommend using `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. These support older asynchronous patterns that ASP.NET 4.0 understands.

Comment: Cannot we use Microsoft.Bcl.Async(C# 5) in ASP.NET 4.0?

Comment: @user960567: No, you cannot. The code will compile but will have undefined behavior. ASP.NET needed changes in some of its core types to properly support `async`/`await`. Some of the details are [on this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx).

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will keep on old APM model.

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.GetByteArrayAsync("url").ContinueWith(t => {
    //insert your code here
});
```

it is work in .net 4.0

Comment: I know how to do this. I am specific about RegisterAsyncTask. This is recommended by the asp.net team, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: What about the example in Hanselman's blog does not work for you?

Comment: @LeonidTsybert, unfortunately it was 4.5